# How is std::condition_variable::wait implemented?

Tags: c++, multithreading, condition-variable

I was trying to search for how `std::conidition_variable::wait` is implemented in the standard library on my local machine, I can see `wait_unitl` but I cannot find `wait`.

My question is, how is the `wait` function implemented internally, how would one make a thread sleep indefinitely, is it using some long timed sleep or something entirely different that is OS-specific?

Thanks!

Comment: have a look here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/libstdc++/api/a00818_source.html

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica It is precisely this piece of code that I cannot find any reference to `_M_cond.wait(__my_lock);` on line 00203

Comment: `wait()` calls into the OS. It's not something that a user-mode process can do for itself. I probably can't answer your question, but you should make it clear whether you are looking for information about how operating system schedulers work in general, specific information about how the scheduler in Linux is implemented, or details of how to implement your own wait()-like function by means of low-level Linux system calls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pre-emptive multithreading is a process governed largely by the operating system. It decides which threads get timeslices and/or assigned to which cores, and so forth. As such, for most low-level threading primitives (mutexes, conditional variables, etc), the real work is done inside OS calls.

Yes, you could *in theory* implement something *like* a conditional variable with nothing more than atomic accesses and timed thread suspension. However, it would perform extremely poorly. Modern OS's know when a thread is waiting on a condition and can wake that thread up "immediately" when the condition is satisfied. Your mechanism requires that the waiting thread wait until some specific time has passed.

Plus, you'd have a whole bunch of spurious wake-ups that you have to check for, thus using thread time for no reason. The OS-based implementation will have far fewer spurious wake-ups.